# wsasend lpnumberofbytesSent

Tags: visual-c++, iocp, overlapped-io

I am using wsasend on an IOCP structured server.
There is one problem.

```
wsabuf [bufcount - 1] .buf = pPacket-> GetPacketBufferPtr ();
wsabuf [bufcount - 1] .len = (int) pPacket-> Get_PacketSize ();
iSendSize + = wsabuf [bufcount - 1] .len;
bufcount ++;
int retval = WSASend (pSession-> socket, wsabuf, bufcount-1, & sendbytes,flag, & pSession-> overlapped_Send, NULL);
if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR)
{

    if (WSAGetLastError ()! = WSA_IO_PENDING)
    {
      ......
    }
}
if (retval == 0)
{
    if (sendbytes! = iSendSize)
    {
       ........
    }
}
.....
```

In the code above, I save the packet to send to wsabuf and I send it through wsasend.
And finally, I compared sendbytes and iSendSize .
By the way, sendbytes and iSendSize are Different.
I do not know why.

Comment: [From the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742203.aspx): "Use `NULL` for this parameter (`lpNumberOfBytesSent`) if the `lpOverlapped` parameter is not `NULL` to avoid potentially erroneous results."

Comment: if you use asynchronous io, you must not use(ignore) `sendbytes`, but `overlapped_Send.InternalHigh` or *NumberOfBytesTransferred* returned by `GetOverlappedResult` (it really simply copy `InternalHigh` value to here) when operation is completed

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The documentation is wrong. On Windows XP with SP2, this will crash with access violation as there is no check for whether the `lpNumberOfBytesSent` is `NULL` or not. `WSASend` works differently on Windows XP. It does not ignore `lpNumberOfBytesSent` even if it was set to `NULL` and the function was called as an overlapped.

Answer (score 1):

the actual number of transferred bytes returned from driver, only when operation is completed. io subsystem copy this value to [`IO_STATUS_BLOCK.Information`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550671(v=vs.85).aspx) transmitted to io operation. as result user get back this value. but of course only after operation is completed.

win32 api use [`OVERLAPPED`](http://OVERLAPPED) in place [`IO_STATUS_BLOCK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550671(v=vs.85).aspx) - reinterpret cast `OVERLAPPED` to `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` and pass this pointer to kernel. so `InternalHigh` will be containing actual number of transferred bytes, but only after operation will be completed (in case error synchronous returned - io subsystem not fill this field, so it value undefined on error. by sense of course 0).

`WSASend` get value (after call to kernel) from `OVERLAPPED.InternalHigh` and if `lpNumberOfBytesSent` not 0 - copy it here. if you use synchronous socket handle - at this moment io operation already will be completed (io subsystem internal wait for this, before return to caller) and valid value from `OVERLAPPED.InternalHigh` will be copied to `*lpNumberOfBytesSent`

in code this will be look like

```
if (!lpOverlapped)
{
    OVERLAPPED Overlapped = {};
    lpOverlapped = &Overlapped;
}

ZwDeviceIoControlFile(.. reinterpret_cast<IO_STATUS_BLOCK*>(lpOverlapped) ..)

if (lpNumberOfBytesSent)
{
  *lpNumberOfBytesSent = (ULONG)lpOverlapped->InternalHigh;
}
```

in case asynchronous socket handle, operation usually yet not finished after return from kernel. as result `lpOverlapped->InternalHigh` yet not filled with correct numbers of bytes. and

```
*lpNumberOfBytesSent = (ULONG)lpOverlapped->InternalHigh;
```

got incorrect (undefined, if you and system not init it, say to 0) result.

conclusion - you can not use `sendbytes` for asynchronous io operation. what here is undefined. you can and need got this value **when io is completed**. how you got it already depend from how you notified about completion.

- if you use [`BindIoCompletionCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363484(v=vs.85).aspx)  - you got it in
  [`FileIOCompletionRoutine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364052(v=vs.85).aspx) in *`dwNumberOfBytesTransfered`*
  argument
- if you use [`CreateThreadpoolIo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682464(v=vs.85).aspx)- you got it in
  [`IoCompletionCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684124(v=vs.85).aspx) in *`NumberOfBytesTransferred`* argument
- if you use own *IOCP* and  [`GetQueuedCompletionStatus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986(v=vs.85).aspx) - you got
  back pointer to your *`lpOverlapped`* used in call to `WSASend` (or
  some another io function - this is already your task determinate
  where this *`lpOverlapped`* used ) after operation was completed. at
  this point you can call [`GetOverlappedResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683209(v=vs.85).aspx) for this
  *`lpOverlapped`* (*`bWait`* you can set to any value - does not matter because operation already completed - the api will return
  immediately in any case without wait) and you got actual number of
  transferred bytes in *`lpNumberOfBytesTransferred`*. however
  [`GetOverlappedResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683209(v=vs.85).aspx) simply copy *`lpOverlapped->InternalHigh`*
  value to `*lpNumberOfBytesTransferred` so you can and direct,
  yourself use `InternalHigh` without call to `GetOverlappedResult`